# Any CSS transition causes jump to html anchor

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a webpage with a jump to a html anchor à la:

```
<a href="#target">Jump</a>
...
<a id="target">Target</a>
```

The jump works fine and the address bar of the browser then shows "`foo.html#target`".

Whenever I then have a CSS transition further down on an element with a `:hover` it causes the page to jump back to the target anchor.

I've been trying to figure out where exactly the problem lies but I'm completely stuck.

Has anybody ever experienced something like this and has an idea what might cause this behavior?

See simplified problem in the snippet below:

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}


#hoverx {
    margin-top: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
    transition: all 2s;
}

#hoverx:hover {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:500px;background-color:#FF0000;">
    <p>DIV1</p>
    <a href="#jump">JUMP</a>
</div>
        
<div style="height:500px;background-color:#00FF00;">
    <p>DIV2</p>
</div>
        
<div style="height:500px;background-color:#0000FF;">
    <p><a id="jump">DIV3</a></p>
</div>

<div style="height:500px;background-color:#FFFF00;"><p>DIV4</p>
    <div id="hoverx">foo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please create a working fiddle to show your example?

Comment: What CSS transition are you using ?

Comment: @SamirChahine: I have not been able to recreate the problem in a simple example. It has to be caused by something in the (unfortunately rather large) css file I am using. I just can't pin it down to what is actually causing it. I was hoping someone might have a general idea through the description of the symptoms.

Comment: @rifa_at_so: The problem occurs with any css transition (background-color, width, height, opacity ...).

Comment: Usually CSS does not really influence your positioning on the page. You sure it snaps back to the anchor or it just accidentally looks like that?

Comment: @somethinghere: absolutely sure it snaps back to the anchor every time your scroll away from it and hit a transitioning object. Edit: acutally _any_ anchor...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SamirChahine: was able to create the fiddle reproducing the behaviour. See https://jsfiddle.net/ptaty09t/

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: The question wasn't "Why isn't this code working?" but rather how can any CSS transition cause a jump to a html anchor. Nonetheless with the updated fiddle hopefully there isn't a problem in any case. Cheers - Tom

Comment: @Tom_s The code seems to work fine in the fiddle, when I clicked `jump` and then hovered over `foo`, the transition worked fine and didn't send me back to the top, are you sure what you're dealing with isn't local?

Answer (score 0):

Since it was working in Firefox, and only having an issue in Chrome, that lead to the culprit. It turned out to be the missing CSS transition prefix:

```
-webkit-transition:
```

With that added, things work as intended.